# Can you plant olive trees in the garden if so how far apart do they need to be?

Tags: trees, olive

How far apart do you need to plant olive trees in the garden not in pots.

Comment: Do you know what variety of olive tree you have?

Comment: No I don't sorry I have had them in pots for approx 2 and half years and wanted to plant them in the garden as they have not done great in pots.

Comment: Google says 20' apart. I'd guess 15' is plenty - if not commercially grown for room between trees for trucks. A little pruning every few years should keep them tidy.